# Design echo data

Tags: php, html, css

I am using echo to show some scroll data from another website.I want to echo data according to that website. I am giving the design of the desired output and the current output. Need some help to resolve the issue.

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<style>
.news {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;

}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


$url = "http://www.dsebd.org/";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();



$html = str_replace('', '', $html);

@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach($divs as $div) {


    if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'panel panel-dse') {
       $data = $div ->nodeValue;
       print_r($data);exit;

    }
}


?>

<marquee style="padding: 0px 15px; height: 500px; width: 30%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 238);" height="500" width="30%" align="top" behavior="scroll" direction="up" onmouseout="this.start();" onmouseover="this.stop();" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="40" truespeed="" bgcolor="#ffffee">

<h2>Daily News Event</h2>

 <?php

  echo $data ; ?>
   </marquee>

 </div>

  <div>
 <input type=button onClick="location.href='Event.php'" value='Last Seven Days News'>

</div>
```

**Current Output**

Today’s News Trading Code: EXCHNews Title: DSENEWS: Greetings MessageHonorable Investors, Good morning! Please make your investment decision based on company fundamentals, technical analysis, price level and disclosed information. Avoid rumor-based speculations.Trading Code: REGLNews Title: BSEC NEWS: Awareness Message for InvestorsInvestors are requested to consider the following facts at the time of making investment decision in the Capital Market: 1. Without acquiring proper knowledge, information and experience regarding different aspects and matters of Capital Market, one should not invest in the Capital Market. 2. The gain or loss, whichever comes from the investment, it belongs to you. So, well - thought of investment decision based on knowledge and fundamentals of the securities may be real assistance to you. (cont.)

**Desired output**

Trading Code: EXCHNews

Title: DSENEWS: Greetings Message

Honorable Investors, Good morning! Please make your investment decision based on company fundamentals, technical analysis, price level and disclosed information. Avoid rumor-based speculations.

Trading Code: REGLNews 
Title: BSEC NEWS: Awareness Message for Investors

Investors are requested to consider the following facts at the time of making investment decision in the Capital Market: 1. Without acquiring proper knowledge, information and experience regarding different aspects and matters of Capital Market, one should not invest in the Capital Market. 2. The gain or loss, whichever comes from the investment, it belongs to you. So, well - thought of investment decision based on knowledge and fundamentals of the securities may be real assistance to you. (cont.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `nl2br()` function.

> Returns string with `'<br />'` or `'<br>'` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

```
echo nl2br($data);
```

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php.